# Creating index file in FME 2018?

Tags: fme-form, spatial-index, transformer

Is there a transformer to create a index file for my shapefile output?

As a .qix file on QGIS.

Comment: define index? (shapefile have .shp, .shx, .dbf - the shx is an index to match the records with the dbf and geometry in the shp.)

Comment: Thanks but I have already worked out the issue. There is a feature "write spatial index" in the Dataset Writer.

Comment: you can post your own answer if this is fixed

Answer (score 4):

FME should support QIX index files for Shape in FME 2019.1  For now, if you want FME to create a QIX file for QGIS then use a FeatureWriter followed by ogrinfo in a SystemCaller.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature "write spatial index" in the Dataset Writer. FME creates two ArcGIS-like index files, .sbn and .sbx.
When I open the shapefile using QGIS, the data loads quicker.